# Rails Issue : "couldn't find file 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I m new to RoR and could not able to fix the error "couldn't find file 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap".

I went through many posts but nothing fixes my issue. There seems either problem in
Gem file (something needed upgrade or remove) OR application.css.scss file which could not find the 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap' OR in "_stylesheets.html.haml" which call the stylesheets.

Could someone pls suggest on this?

---

**Error:**

ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap'
  (in /root/rails_project/res_dash/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:11)):

```
1: -# CSS: implied media="all"
2: -# = stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/screen', :media => 'all
3: = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'screen'
```

**_stylesheets.html.haml**

```
-# CSS: implied media="all"
-# = stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/screen', :media => 'all'

= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'screen'
```

**application.css.scss**

```
 *= require bootstrap/css/bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive
 *= require font-awesome/sass/font-awesome
 *= require css/style
 *= require css/style_responsive
 *= require css/style_default
 *= require gritter/css/jquery.gritter
 *= require uniform/css/uniform.default
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
 *= require dataTables/extras/TableTools_JUI
 *= require bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker
 *= require chosen
 *= require fancybox
 *= require dashboard
 *= require res-layout
 *= require_self
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "sass"
gem "sass-rails"
gem "haml
.
.
.
.
gem "haml-rails"
gem "compass"
gem "chosen-rails", "~> 0.12.0"
gem "therubyracer"
gem "bootstrap-sass", "2.3.2.0"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "less-rails"
```

Comment: Have you run the generator task? Also, I didn't see any reference on the pages for those gems to include those CSS files in your application.css. Where did you see instructions to include them?

Comment: It seems to be overkill to inlude both bootsrtap-sass and twitter-bootstrap-rails. They seem to for approximately the same thing. I checked the documentation for both (something you also could do) and nowhere was there any mention of `*= require bootstrap/css/bootstrap` so try to import/include/whatever as documented and see where that leads you.

Comment: thanks @froderik , i tried to **import "bootstrap"** in application.css.scss file and that worked for me!

Comment: good to hear. have fun with bootstrap!